# Tensorflow DNNClassifier and scikit-learn GridSearchCV issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, scikit-learn

It's been a few hours now that I tried performing an hyperparameters optimization over a tensorflow DNN model using `GridSearchCV`. The latest version of my code is the following:

```
import random
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python import learn
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

random.seed(42)
iris = datasets.load_iris()
feature_columns = learn.infer_real_valued_columns_from_input(iris.data)
classifier = learn.DNNClassifier(
          feature_columns=feature_columns,
          hidden_units=[10, 20, 10],
          n_classes=3)
grid_search = GridSearchCV(
          classifier, {'hidden_units': [[5, 5], [10, 10]]},
          scoring='accuracy',
          fit_params={'steps': [50]})
grid_search.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
score = accuracy_score(iris.target, grid_search.predict(iris.data))
```

I have actually taken it from [a test in the `tensorflow` library itself](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/grid_search_test.py).

When I run it I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-dce950001f99> in <module>()
     16           scoring='accuracy',
     17           fit_params={'steps': [50]})
---> 18 grid_search.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
     19 score = accuracy_score(iris.target, grid_search.predict(iris.data))

/home/nmiotto/Development/upday/hellseher/playground/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups)
    943             train/test set.
    944         """
--> 945         return self._fit(X, y, groups, ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
    946 
    947 

/home/nmiotto/Development/upday/hellseher/playground/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py in _fit(self, X, y, groups, parameter_iterable)
    548                                      n_candidates * n_splits))
    549 
--> 550         base_estimator = clone(self.estimator)
    551         pre_dispatch = self.pre_dispatch
    552 

/home/nmiotto/Development/upday/hellseher/playground/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in clone(estimator, safe)
     68     for name, param in six.iteritems(new_object_params):
     69         new_object_params[name] = clone(param, safe=False)
---> 70     new_object = klass(**new_object_params)
     71     params_set = new_object.get_params(deep=False)
     72 

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'params'
```

I am using `Python 3.5.2` have updated all the libraries to the latest version, more precisely:

```
$ pip3 freeze
numpy==1.12.1
scikit-learn==0.18.1
scipy==0.19.0
tensorflow==1.1.0
```

I ran out of ideas, I can't figure out what I am missing. Any help would be appreciated. 
I am assuming of course that I don't have to monkey patch or hack anything into the existing libraries.

Answer (score 3):

This issue comes from cloning the estimator, as specified in the stack error.

```
new_object = klass(**new_object_params)
```

The `new_object_params` is returned some lines above by:

```
new_object_params = estimator.get_params(deep=False)
```

As you observe, estimator is your DNNClassifier, whose clone is being made to do gridsearchCV. But the `estimator.get_params(deep=False)` returns the following:

```
{'params': {'head': <tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators.head._MultiClassHead object at 0x7f720df04490>, 
'hidden_units': [10, 20, 10], 
'feature_columns': (_RealValuedColumn(column_name='', dimension=4, default_value=None, dtype=tf.float64, normalizer=None),),
'embedding_lr_multipliers': None, 'optimizer': None, 'dropout': None,
'gradient_clip_norm': None, 
'activation_fn': <function relu at 0x7f7221aa8b18>, 'input_layer_min_slice_size': None}}
```

As you see the first parameter is named `params`. Now this will be tried to set into the init_method of DNNClassifier to get new object.

But in version 1.1.0 of tenserflow, the init parameter looks like this:

```
  def __init__(self,
               hidden_units,
               feature_columns,
               model_dir=None,
               n_classes=2,
               weight_column_name=None,
               optimizer=None,
               activation_fn=nn.relu,
               dropout=None,
               gradient_clip_norm=None,
               enable_centered_bias=False,
               config=None,
               feature_engineering_fn=None,
               embedding_lr_multipliers=None,
               input_layer_min_slice_size=None,
               label_keys=None):
...
...
```

There is no parameter named `params` here. Hence the error.

But if you see the current master branch of tensorflow for the `init()` method, its like this:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn.py#L327

```
    super(DNNClassifier, self).__init__(
        model_fn=_dnn_model_fn,
        model_dir=model_dir,
        config=config,
        params={
            "head":
                head_lib.multi_class_head(
                    n_classes,
                    weight_column_name=weight_column_name,
                    enable_centered_bias=enable_centered_bias,
                    label_keys=label_keys),
            "hidden_units": hidden_units,
            "feature_columns": self._feature_columns,
            "optimizer": optimizer,
            "activation_fn": activation_fn,
            "dropout": dropout,
            "gradient_clip_norm": gradient_clip_norm,
            "embedding_lr_multipliers": embedding_lr_multipliers,
            "input_layer_min_slice_size": input_layer_min_slice_size,
        },
        feature_engineering_fn=feature_engineering_fn)
```

So maybe that test you looked in the master branch is related to this code change. You can download the current branch and compile the library yourself, to remove this error.

Or else, search how to grid search in version 1.1.0.

Comment: I tried the current master version, but still no luck (same error). Also, it seems that that test is not really working, and it's probably not really a test but more like a hacky script they wrote to try something out long time ago and that now broke

Comment: @NicolaMiotto I havent checked it using the master branch. I'll get back to you after testing. Meanwhile, you can use a combination of ParameterGrid and cross_val_score to the same effect. If you need, I can edit the answer here to include it.